# Prove that the sequence converges to using the ε - N definition of a limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, epsilon-delta

This is more of a solution verification request than anything else. Feedback would be much appreciated.

**Question**: Prove that the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ defined by $a_n=\frac{n+37}{n^5-2n^2}$ converges to $0$ using the $\varepsilon$-$N$ definition of a limit.

**Solution:**  Need to show that $\forall\epsilon>0$, $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n>N \implies|a_n-0|<\varepsilon.$

Fix $\epsilon>0$.

We have $\left|a_n-0\right|=\left|\frac{n+37}{n^5-2n^2}\right|$.

Now $n+37\le n+37n=38n$ provided $n \ge1$.

Likewise $n^5-2n^2\ge n^5-\frac{1}{2}n^5=\frac{1}{2}n^5$ provided $\frac{1}{2}n^5\ge 2n^2$, which is true provided $n^3\ge 4$ i.e when $n\ge 2$.

Then we have $\left|\frac{n+37}{n^5-2n^2}\right|\le\left|\frac{38n}{\frac{1}{2}n^5}\right|=\left|\frac{76}{n^4}\right|=\frac{76}{n^4}$

Then $\frac{76}{n^4}<\epsilon \iff\frac{n^4}{76}>\frac{1}{\epsilon}\iff n>\sqrt[4]\frac{76}{\epsilon}$

So choose $N=\lfloor\sqrt[4]\frac{76}{\epsilon}\rfloor+1$ and the definition is satisfied. Q.E.D.

Comment: I think we may provide more elementary and primitive bound for $n$; for example, we know $1/n^4\le 1/n$ so $n>76/\varepsilon$ suffices.

Comment: Anyway, your proof is correct.

Comment: The proof is good, but we can find more strict conditions, for example, why use the fact that $n^5-2n^2\ge n^5-\frac12n^5$ it will be simpler to use the fact $n^5-2n^2\ge n^2-2n^2=-n^2$ with this you get $a_n\le \frac{38}{n}$ hence $\frac{38}n<\epsilon\iff n>\frac{38}{\epsilon}\rightarrow N=\lfloor\frac{38}{\epsilon}\rfloor+1$